# Encrypted online backup with snapshots for Linux

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

My current backup is with Back In Time on multiple external HDDs. This is nice as it has snapshots and encryption (with LUKS). It protects against hardware failures, user errors and malware attacks. The only downside is that I have to manually start it, and this means that I won't do it every day.

For a while I used a non-public directory on my webspace and did a backup via SSH. This was automatic, though not encrypted on the server side and space was limited. If could be encrypted with EncFS, though that is not as secure as LUKS.

I would like to have an online backup that would be encrypted and with snapshots. The amount of data is around 250 GB. The one service that I know of is SpiderOak. It has a Linux desktop client that encrypts the file on my computer. The only caveat with it is that is hosted in the USA, though I would prefer one in Germany.

The alternative would be buying a small computer as a NAS running Linux with LUKS. But that does not really help me if I am not at home.

Are there more services that offer the following?

- Snapshots
- Linux support
- Encryption
- Online

---

In the meantime I found these articles:

- https://www.cloudwards.net/best-online-backup-for-linux/
- https://www.starryhope.com/online-backup-solutions-for-ubuntu-linux/
- https://www.techgrube.de/programme-und-webdienste/cloudbackup-mit-dem-linux-desktop (German)

It seems that the following services are worth looking into:

- Crashplan
- pCloud
- Spider Oak

Comment: "`The only downside is that I have to manually start it`". if that is ***truly*** the only downside, then use a `cron` job.   "... buying a NAS ... does not really help me if I am not at home" - use OpenVpn and access your PC remotely.

Comment: Did you ever fin a solution? If so, please accept an answer or post your own answer and accept it. That will help others in future. If you don't it might look like the question is unanswerable, which I doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried out SpiderOak but found that the upload performance is not sufficient. At work I have around 200 MBit/s upload speed and I still found it uploading at 1 MBit/s or less. Uploading the 150 GB that I planned to upload did not finish in a week. I fear that with the frequency that I change files, the upload is insufficient to keep up.

Their GUI is nice, though recovering multiple files from a specific point in time takes the command line; which I do not mind.

Eventually I settled on Duplicity and Backblaze B2 storage. This encrypts the files either symmetric or asymmetric using GPG on my computer. Storage on Backblaze B2 is cheap and their pricing model is easier to understand than Amazon S3 with its various storage classes (normal, slow, Glacier).

Upload performance is sufficient and once you have set up a bucket for storage one needs just one longish command of duplicity to get incremental backups working.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently behind my office firewall, so may have to update this when I get home, if you need any more info.

I used to use SpiderOak, and having nothing negative to say about it.

My reasons for moving were price. You (currently) have only 2650gB, so your plan may not be too expensive. For $45year (if I remember correctly), I am now using [BackBlaze](https://help.backblaze.com), which offers unlimited backups, including from external drives, so I have about 7tB up there(!).

Of course, it is encrypted (I can't visit their web page to quote from it).

For Linux, yes, you can- see https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217664628-How-does-Backblaze-support-Linux-Users-